# Facebook apprequest notification received but not showing message

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The notification is received but without the message.
Any idea why? Did facebook removed messages even that it's in the dev doc?

```
function newInvite(){
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'Invite friends to play',
    message: 'Come to play.',
    new_style_message: true, // added this after a search but doesnt work either
    filters: ['app_non_users']
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#dialogparameters:

> message: A plain-text message to be sent as part of the request. This text will surface in the App Center view of the request, but not on the notification jewel

So yes, if you are talking about the notification jewel (the little globe symbol in the top bar in the web UI), this is supposed to work this way - there it will only show a text given by Facebook, “Foobar send you a request on Appname” or something like that.

Only the detailed App Center view under https://www.facebook.com/games/activity is supposed to show the message the user sending the request typed in.